# Guice Filter on Appengine dev server returns 404 when module set to Manual Scaling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, guice

I am using appengine dev server with manual scaling mode. A GuiceFilter is used to serve my servlet. When running on the development server, the GuiceFilter will return a 404 when I access the servlet through the module port, but it will work fine if I try to access through one of the instances ports.

Here is an extract of my appengine-web.xml:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>${appengine.app.name}</application>
    <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </manual-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I use guiceFilter as follows in my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My GuiceFilter is defined as:

```
public class GuiceModule extends GuiceSystemServiceServletModule {
  @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {
    super.configureServlets();
  }
}

public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
  protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(
        new GuiceModule(),
        new ServletModule() {
          @Override
          protected void configureServlets() {
            serve("/testGuiceServlet").with(TestServlet.class);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

I run the dev server with:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

At this point I can observe logs similar to:

```
Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Module instance default instance 0 is running at http://localhost:61190/
```

If I try accessing my servlet through  http://localhost:61190/testGuiceServlet it will work. But when I try to use the module port http://localhost:8080/testGuiceServlet, then a 404 is returned!

In the logs I can read:

```
[INFO] Feb 26, 2016 6:35:48 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
[INFO] WARNING: No file found for: /testGuiceServlet
```

I get no such issues if I use instead of GuiceFilter a standard Servlet in my web.xml. I also do not get any such issue if I use dynamic scaling instead of manual scaling. It also works fine on the production Appengine.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and setting the scaling to automatic fixes it - thanks! Also, I've tried this a couple of months ago and I think it used to work, so it might be a recent issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Guice, but in filters working on devserv.
See some workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373566/4774310)