# Servlet filters not working with AppEngine manual scaling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlet-filters

I am using Google AppEngine with java.
I have configured for manual scaling by adding the following in appengine-web.xml

```
<manual-scaling>
    <instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
```

But after I add this, I am not able to use servlet filters with the following mapping in web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>testFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.fms.test.TestFilter</filter-class> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>testFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>  
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

The filters will work if I give * as url-pattern, but that is not my requirement. Without the manual scaling, it is working as expected.

Can anybody tell me why I cant use it?

PS: I am in development environment and using AppEngine SDK version 1.9.42

Here is my  filter code:

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter { 
    private static final AdvocacyUtils utils = AdvocacyUtils.getInstance();

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Request filtered.");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the servlet mapping as well that you are trying to hook?
Are you trying in the development or production environment?

Comment: There are no servlets, just filters. I added the mapping. I used the term "servlet filters" for not confusing with others. I am in development environment.

Comment: But the filter which service need to hook? The url-pattern you configured is related to an http endpoint, so where is the declaration of it?

Comment: I updated the question with source code of filter. @DevilingMaster is this what you meant by declaration? The /_ah/api/* is Google Cloud Endpoint url for APIs

Answer (score 4):

I've found some workaround ([here](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/issues/307))
Solution is to add into the "filter-mapping" aditional section - "dispatcher" like in this snippet:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks for this workaround/hack. 7 years after this was posted this answer is still relevant - I just wasted half a day figuring this out. I'd expect this to have been fixed in appengine by now. I can't figure out why switching from auto to basic scaling would require a change in web.xml. Anyone know the answer to this?